# Menu Wordpress com Mega Menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu

Uso um plugin no `wordpress` chamado mega menu, so que ele duplicou meu
menu, ai dei uma pesquisada e segundo a pesquisa eu deveria
ir no header e achar o locar do mega menu e deletar uma das div, ate ai sussa
achei e tls porem me deparei com isso

```
<div class="span9">
                        <div class="nav" id="navigation">
                            <?php navigation(); ?>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Ali no  deveria estar o codigo do mega menu :D
então comecei a busca por esse navigation  e ate agora não tive exito alguem poderia me dar uma luz

Comment: Experimenta trocar o `<?php navigation(); ?>` por `<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>` e diz-me se ele ficou bem

Comment: Infelizmente nao meu amigo, ele perdeu o css do mega menu, e ficou em coluna, porem, nao duplicou mais gostaria de manter o mega menu :D ele é bem bacana!!

Comment: Bom, é complicado aprofundar no problema assim às escuras e com pouca informação, mas podes remover todo o bloco de código do menu indesejado (pelo menos evitar que ele seja exibido) aplicando um `display:none;` no CSS do *container* que segura todo o bloco desse menu.